# Whats the difference between WorksheetFunction.IsNumber() and IsNumeric() in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, function

Whats the different between using these two functions in VBA?  Is there a speed advantage of using one over the other?

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(myVar)
IsNumeric(myVar)
```

Comment: If you're looking for a reason to use one over the other, there's a discussion in the VBA Rubberducking chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14929?m=43516169#43516169), and a [relevant closed issue](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14929?m=43516169#43516169) on the Rubberduck GitHub repo. Use the VBA function if equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** Unless you have a specific reason to use Excel's semantics for the function (i.e. replicating the result it would give in a cell, don't use `IsNumber` if you care about performance.

First of all, the result (and performance) is going to differ based on the data type that is passed into the function. If you're pulling values directly from the Worksheet, you have to be aware of the fact that Excel is going to cast the value differently depending on how you access it:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Debug.Print IsNumeric("1e12")   'True
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber("1e12")  'False
    [A1] = "1e12"
    'The next 2 are the same, but the first is an implicit call to .Value
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber([A1])    'True 
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber([A1].Value)    'True
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber([A1].Text)    'False
End Sub
```

Next, there is a small overhead of the dereferencing calls against `WorksheetFunction`, so I'll control for that in the benchmarks below by wrapping it in a `With` block. Note also the difference in performance (and return value o_O) between handling a string and a number:

```
Private Const ITERATIONS As Long = 1000000

Private Sub RunAll()
    Test 1000
    Test "1000"
End Sub

Private Sub Test(testValue As Variant)
    IsNumericBenchMark testValue
    IsNumberBenchMark testValue
End Sub

Private Sub IsNumericBenchMark(inputValue As Variant)
    Dim start As Single, i As Long
    start = Timer
    For i = 1 To ITERATIONS
        IsNumeric inputValue
    Next
    Debug.Print "IsNumeric" & vbTab & Timer - start & vbTab & IsNumeric(inputValue)
End Sub

Private Sub IsNumberBenchMark(inputValue As Variant)
    Dim start As Single, i As Long
    start = Timer
    With WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To ITERATIONS
            .IsNumber inputValue
        Next
    End With
    Debug.Print "IsNumber" & vbTab & Timer - start & vbTab & WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(inputValue)
End Sub
```

Results:

```
IsNumeric   0.09375     True
IsNumber    5.664063    True
IsNumeric   0.6796875   True
IsNumber    6.796875    False
```

It's official, `IsNumber` is not exactly a top performer.

Comment: What do you mean by dereferening please? I have only a vague notion.

Comment: The `.` is the VBA dereference operator. `WorksheetFunction` is an interface on the `Application` object, and the `.` between them gets you a reference to that interface from the object. Hence, "dereferencing". There is actual work being performed by processing the `.`. The `With` block holds an object reference, so it prevents repeated dereferences of `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I almost want to mark this as the answer just for teaching me how to easily benchmark.

Comment: `ITERATIONS` is an undeclared constant? ;)

Comment: Yes, I tested this out and created a private constant above the code from @Comintern.  That worked!  `Private Const ITERATIONS_MULTIPLIER As Long = 1000`

Comment: @FreeMan Copy and paste error, fixed. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 11):

[`IsNumeric`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isnumeric-function) is a VBA standard library function located in the `VBA.Information` module, like `IsArray`, `IsDate`, `IsError`, `Err`, `VarType`, and more:

[image: VBE Object Browser showing IsNumeric in the VBA standard library]

As part of the VBA standard library, it works regardless of the host application: the standard library is safe to presume as existing on a machine that runs VBA.

[`Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-isnumber-method-excel), on the other hand, is found in the Microsoft Excel object model library:

[image: VBE Object Browser showing IsNumber in the Excel type library]

As such, the code can only work if the Excel type library is referenced. If you're already in Excel, that's not a problem. But if you're in Word and you would like to use a function that returns a `Boolean` when the given `String` is numeric, you don't want to reference the whole Excel type library just for that.

The `WorksheetFunction` interface is a gateway to Excel's calculation engine: with it, you can write VBA code that can now use INDEX/MATCH against carefully crafted plain-VBA arrays - it's completely awesome. But there's no guarantee that Excel's calculation engine works exactly the same way VBA does. If you want to go by Excel's rules, use `WorksheetFunction`.

I would probably presume `VBA.Information.IsNumeric` to be faster than `Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber` though: I could be wrong, but it seems like fewer moving parts are involved with just the VBA standard library.

But the only way to find out:

> You have two horses - race them!

;-)

Comment: `?IsNumeric("999")` is true but `?Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber("999")` is false.

Comment: That's because "999" is not a number - it is a string.  IsNumber checks the type of the variant while IsNumeric checks if it can be converted.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-isnumber-method-excel  `The value arguments of the IS functions are not converted. For example, in most other functions where a number is required, the text value "19" is converted to the number 19. However, in the formula ISNUMBER("19"), "19" is not converted from a text value, and the ISNUMBER function returns FALSE.`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The caveat to that is that it depends on whether or not you're pulling data from the cell with `.Value` (which casts it to a `Variant`) or processing it as `String` data from inside the VBA procedure.

Comment: My punishment for asking two questions in one post is that I get two fantastic answers (thanks to @Comintern and @MathieuGuindon).  I'm marking this as the answer because it explains the difference thoroughly and reasons to one or the other depending on use.

Comment: @ChrisB to be fair the "thorough difference" is behind links to the Microsoft documentation; my answer [intentionally] leaves much of the *actual* answer up to the reader, whereas Comintern's answer is more explicit about when to use each function, and how they perform: I'm surprised with the amount of votes this answer got.. I wouldn't mind you giving Comintern's answer the checkmark at all ;-)

Comment: I already marked yours as the answer, but if someone asks me to dereference them reference another, who am I to argue ; )