# Application.WorksheetFunction.Search and .IsNumber don't work in VBA: type mismatch error; fixing match function character limit

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to work around the `MATCH`'s function's character limit using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504620):

> =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,Dict!A:A)),0),0))

I tried the full version:

```
Sub test

  Dim KEY_CONTRACT_ROW As Variant
  KEY_CONTRACT_ROW = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(True, _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("testing string", _
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))), 0), 0)

End Sub
```

It didn't work - `Type mismatch error`.

So I tried the shorter version:

```
Sub test

  MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("testing string", _
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))))

End Sub
```

To the same result. At the same time when I use this formula manually on worksheet it works fine.

Comment: FYI, VBA has the built-in `ISNUMERIC()` function. No need for the worksheetfunction `ISNUMBER()`.

Comment: It is also applied in the sheet as an array formula no? So not sure if that means you need to treat it differently in the above.

Comment: @BruceWayne [they don't do the same thing at all though](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51549786/1188513)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Oh!  Woah! I didn't know that, thanks so much for pointing that out.

Comment: @QHarr What do you mean? I  don't use array formulas here. All I use is the given code.

Comment: @Ans why do you want to use worksheet functions or formulas if you are going to use VBA already? maybe if you explain what your final goal is we can come up with better ideas

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that INDEX/ISNUMBER/SEARCH actually returns an array, and that INDEX is used in this case simply to allow the formula to be confirmed with just ENTER, instead of CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Answer (score 1):

`WorksheetFunction` produces a breaking error when an error occurs.  Instead, use the Match method of the Application object.  Actually, you can avoid `WorksheetFunction` altogether.

```
Sub test()

    Dim KEY_CONTRACT_ROW As Variant
    Dim rngSearchRange As Range

    'Define the search range as to avoid a whole column reference
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngSearchRange = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A"))
    End With

    'Search for the specified search string
    With Application
        KEY_CONTRACT_ROW = .Match(True, .IsNumber(.Search("testing string", rngSearchRange)), 0)
    End With

    'Check whether a match was found
    If IsError(KEY_CONTRACT_ROW) Then
        MsgBox "Match not found!", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "Match found!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```